# JAMA is not calculating the right eigen vectors

Tags: java, jama

I have the following matrix, which is symmetric and real (It is a hamilton-operator):
(Matlab friendly)

[63.000000, -1.732051, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000; -1.732051, 61.000000, -2.000000, 0.000000, -1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000; 0.000000, -2.000000, 61.000000, -1.732051, 0.000000, -1.414214, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000; 0.000000, 0.000000, -1.732051, 63.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, -1.732051, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000; 0.000000, -1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 61.000000, -1.414214, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000; 0.000000, 0.000000, -1.414214, 0.000000, -1.414214, 60.000000, -1.414214, -1.414214, 0.000000, 0.000000; 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, -1.732051, 0.000000, -1.414214, 61.000000, 0.000000, -2.000000, 0.000000; 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, -1.414214, 0.000000, 61.000000, -1.000000, 0.000000; 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, -2.000000, -1.000000, 61.000000, -1.732051; 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, -1.732051, 63.000000]

If i make a JAMA-matrix with these values, and execute the eigenvalue decomposition, V*D*transpose(V) does NOT equal the hamilton. Do any of you guys know what goes wrong? The eigenvalues are consistent with MATLAB, but the eigenvectors are not.

Here is a class to test it

```
public class TestJama {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    double[][] m = new double[][] {
            {63.000000, -1.732051, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000},
            { -1.732051, 61.000000, -2.000000, 0.000000, -1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000},
            { 0.000000, -2.000000, 61.000000, -1.732051, 0.000000, -1.414214, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000},
            { 0.000000, 0.000000, -1.732051, 63.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, -1.732051, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000},
            { 0.000000, -1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 61.000000, -1.414214, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000},
            { 0.000000, 0.000000, -1.414214, 0.000000, -1.414214, 60.000000, -1.414214, -1.414214, 0.000000, 0.000000},
            { 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, -1.732051, 0.000000, -1.414214, 61.000000, 0.000000, -2.000000, 0.000000},
            { 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, -1.414214, 0.000000, 61.000000, -1.000000, 0.000000},
            { 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, -2.000000, -1.000000, 61.000000, -1.732051},
            { 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, -1.732051, 63.000000}
    };


    Matrix hamilton = new Matrix(m);
    System.out.println(jamaToString(hamilton));

    EigenvalueDecomposition e = hamilton.eig();
    System.out.println(jamaToString(e.getD()));
    System.out.println(jamaToString(e.getV()));

    Matrix recomb = e.getV().times(e.getD()).times(e.getV().transpose());
    System.out.println(jamaToString(recomb));

    System.out.println(hamilton.equals(recomb));

}

private static String jamaToString(Matrix m) {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    b.append("[");
    for(int i=0; i<m.getRowDimension(); i++) {

        for(int j=0; j<m.getColumnDimension(); j++) {
            b.append(m.get(i, j));
            if(j<m.getColumnDimension() - 1) b.append(",");
        }
        if(i<m.getRowDimension() - 1) b.append(";");
    }
    b.append("]");
    return b.toString();
}
}
```

EDIT:
The result (V*D*transpose(V)) yields

63.1093   -0.6379    0.3400   -0.6576    0.0938   -0.0437   -0.6056   -0.5066    0.3463  0.5039
   -0.6379   61.3082   -0.2368   -1.7813   -0.0851    0.7949   -0.1337    0.7668   -0.0422   -2.4329
    0.3400   -0.2368   60.1481    1.3323   -0.4099   -1.8834   -0.5780    0.7516    0.0946    0.1705
   -0.6576   -1.7813    1.3323   61.2455    0.0972   -0.8075   -0.9004    0.0242    0.3963   -1.2527
    0.0938   -0.0851   -0.4099    0.0972   60.3086   -0.1899    0.0394    0.1987   -0.0484   -0.1495
   -0.0437    0.7949   -1.8834   -0.8075   -0.1899   61.7941    0.3741    0.8237    0.7772    0.7557
   -0.6056   -0.1337   -0.5780   -0.9004    0.0394    0.3741   60.6415    0.6351    0.7099    0.3349
   -0.5066    0.7668    0.7516    0.0242    0.1987    0.8237    0.6351   62.8108    1.3507    1.3002
    0.3463   -0.0422    0.0946    0.3963   -0.0484    0.7772    0.7099    1.3507   63.3270    0.1244
    0.5039   -2.4329    0.1705   -1.2527   -0.1495    0.7557    0.3349    1.3002    0.1244   60.3069

Comment: If the output that you inserted is really the result of printing `recomb`, then there indeed seems something to be wrong. Which version of JAMA are you using? I just tested it with version 1.0.3, and there, the "epsilonEquals" (from my answer below) returned `true` - which would not be the case if the `recomb` matrix looked like the one that you posted...

Comment: Seems like the new version works. I am not sure which old version i was using, but thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

If it is only about the value of the matrix: It is correct.

> EDIT: The above statement was written *before* the resulting matrix was inserted into the original question. Of course, this matrix is *not* correct. According to the comments, it seems that this wrong matrix was caused by some bug in an older JAMA version. With JAMA 1.0.3 it worked. The remaining part of this answer is still valid and relevant for the question nevertheless:

There are two problems here. First of all, the `equals` method of the JAMA `Matrix` class is not overridden to compare the *contents* of the matrices. And the default implementation of `equals` compares for *identity* of the referred objects. So even a trivial comparison like this

```
Matrix A = new Matrix(new double[][]{{1.0}});
Matrix B = new Matrix(new double[][]{{1.0}});
System.out.println(A.equals(B));
```

would print `false`.

The second problem is rather simple (and common) : Computations with `double` values are not infinitely precise. You can find many questions about this on StackOverflow, but might want to have a look at [Wikipedia about Floating Point Accuracy Problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems). (Some people would recommend the article about [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), but it's rather involved...).

The basic problem can easily reproduced with this small example:

```
double x = 0.1;
double y = 0;
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    y += x;
}
System.out.println(y+" == 1.0: "+(y==1.0));
```

The result of this computation is **not** `y==1.0`, but `y==0.99999999999999...` instead.

So even **if** the `equals` method was overridden to perform an element-wise comparison, the comparison would still yield `false` due to the floating point error.

One way of alleviating this problem is to check whether some values are "equal up to a small epsilon". This may still be tricky, because the magnitude of the values to be compared will make a difference here, but one solution could be to use the following method to compare matrices for epsilon-equality:

```
private static boolean epsilonEqual(Matrix a, Matrix b)
{
    int ra = a.getRowDimension();
    int rb = b.getRowDimension();
    if (ra != rb)
    {
        return false;
    }
    int ca = a.getColumnDimension();
    int cb = b.getColumnDimension();
    if (ca != cb)
    {
        return false;
    }
    for (int c=0; c<ca; c++)
    {
        for (int r=0; r<ra; r++)
        {
            double ea = a.get(r, c);
            double eb = b.get(r, c);
            if (!epsilonEqual(ea, eb))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private static boolean epsilonEqual(double x, double y)
{
  final double epsilon = 1e-8;
  return Math.abs(x - y) <= epsilon;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that very good answer. Looking at the explicit result, though, i would say that is not because of computer precision? It shouldn't be i guess, when for instance MATLAB can do it?

Comment: @gedemagt There are ways of solving computation tasks like this with higher precision. In Java, it is *theoretically* possible to perform "arbitrary precision" computations with `java.math.BigDecimal` (but you should not consider to use it in such a case, it's highly impractical). I'm not familiar enough with MATLAB to know *how* it is working internally, and what lets you think that is is correct, but ... I'll add another comment to the original question...